# Combining Google's Drive API and Spreadsheets API leads to "Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define..." errors

Tags: android

In order to integate my app with GDrive I have followed the tutorial on https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

In step 3 of the tutorial, the tutorial recommends to install the [Google Eclipse plugin](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) to take care of the library setup (this plugin let's you choose which's Google API's to use and creates the /libs folder including the jars for you). 
The tutorial shows how to take a picture and upload it to Google Drive.

After working through the tutorial I decided to extend the example: since my app works with Google Spreadsheets I added the spreadsheets API (using the Google Eclipse Plugin) to the example.

The application compiles but on run-time I do get the following error:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Ljavax/annotation/CheckForNull;
```

My feeling is that some libraries are conflicting, but these libraries are all calculated using the Google Eclipse plugin? How is this possible and how should I resolve this issue?

My (generatd) libs folder looks like this (contains the Google Drive API v2 and Spreadsheets API):

```
gdata-client-1.0.jar
gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar
gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0.jar
google-api-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-api-client-android-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-api-services-drive-v2-rev55-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar
google-http-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-android-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-gson-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-jackson-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-jackson2-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-oauth-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
gson-2.1.jar
guava-jdk5-13.0.jar
jackson-core-2.0.5.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
jsr305.jar
```

Thanks for any help,
Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. Removing the jsr305.jar from the libs folder solved the problem for me.

Comment: Tp get rid of the Dalvik errors a combination of the answer above and switching towards a build based on Gradle has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bin and gen folders and Build the project

or

check multiple private libraries added to your project

or

check whether the multiple play services added to your project